# An issue with limiting a while loop

Tags: php, mysqli, while-loop

My table auto increments the value `KundeID` and on the form that confirms the input of data I want to show the person inputting it what their ID is when they're done. I'm using this code currently and while I get the correct ID, it loops forever, but I only want it to tell the ID once. What can I do to fix this?

```
$sq="SELECT MAX(KundeID) AS max_ID FROM kunder";
while   ($result=mysqli_query($kobling,$sq)) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo "Ditt kundenummer er ".$row["max_ID"]."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: I think you don't really need a `while` loop.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for something else that could work?

Comment: With a `while` loop you execute the same instruction many times. Just execute the same instruction once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is:

```
$sq="SELECT MAX(KundeID) AS max_ID FROM kunder";
$result = mysqli_query($kobling,$sq);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo "Ditt kundenummer er " . $row["max_ID"] . "<br>";
```

You don't need to use `while` here.

Answer (score 0):

As you mention table auto increments the value **KundeID** and you want maximum or latest Id, Right ?

So no need to use while loop you can directly get value using query
your code should be like this:

```
 $sq="select KundeID from kunder order by KundeID desc limit 1";

 $result=mysqli_query($kobling,$sq);

 $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 echo "Ditt kundenummer er ".$row["KundeID"]. "<br>";
```

This may help you.